# What do I have to return? method insert

Tags: java

We seem to have a problem implementing the insert method that is given to us in the ListInterface. Can you help us with finding the right type to return?

```
//Method in class list:
public ListInterface insert(E d) {
    Node c = new Node(d, null, current);
    current.prior = c;

    return ????;
}

public interface ListInterface<E extends Data<E>> extends Clonable<ListInterface<E>> {

}


private class Node{ // Inner class for the implementation of the List class.
    E data;
    Node prior,
        next;

    public Node(E d) {
        this(d, null, null);
    }

    public Node(E data, Node prior, Node next) {
        this.data = data == null ? null : data;
        this.prior = prior;
        this.next = next;
    }
}
```

Comment: As defined you have to return a `ListInterface`, or an instance of a class that implements it.  To be frank, though, you would want to return some kind of `boolean` to indicate that the element was added; this is how the Java Collections Framework does it now.

Answer (score 2):

In Java, the return type is specified in the function declaration keywords

```
public ListInterface insert(E d) {
```

`public`, meaning accessible outside its class scope, followed by `ListInterFace`, which is the return type the function is expected to return. It could also be `void`, `String`, `Double`, etc, any datatype.

In this case, your function expects you to return a `ListInferface` object.

Somewhere in your `insert` function, you'll need to instantiate your return object, somewhere along the lines of:

```
ListInferfaceImplement x = new ListInterfaceImplement();
//do list stuff
return x;
```

Edit: you may not be instantiating that exact object (I believe comments say you can't instantiate an interface), but an object that implements this interface.

If you want `Node` to be returned by the insert method, you'll need to have the `Node` class implement the `ListInterface`

```
private class Node implements ListInterface {
```

Comment: @drgPP:  You can create an instance of an anonymous class that implements it, though.

Comment: I have a question would `public ListInterface insert(E d) {` accept any class that implements the `Listinterface` as a return value? Would be great @Makoto I overread the "insert" in his function and thought that he didnt specified his returnvalue at all :P

Comment: @Makoto i didn't say you can't create a instance of an anonymous class or a class that implements the interface, i said you can NOT instantiate an interface. And the OP's previous line of code `ListInterface instance = new ListInterface();` was definitely not an anonymous class instantiation.

Comment: I think I made the right edits. OP will want to have Node implement ListInterface is they want to return a Node instance from the insert method.

Answer (score 1):

It is very strange to return the list implementation after an item has been added to the list.

Preffered approach is a success/failure value - a boolean.

But if you want to proceed with this, then say you are writing the implementation for say LinkedList then,

```
class LinkedList extends ListInterface{
public ListInterface insert(E d) {
    Node c = new Node(d, null, current);
    current.prior = c;

    return this;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the `insert` function is designed to allow for chaining. It will allow you to chain method calls together like so :

```
// For the sake of example, assume String implements Data<E> 
// and that List<E> implements ListInterface<E>.

ListInterface<String> list = new List<>();
list.insert("a")
    .insert("b")
    .insert("c");
```

The idea is that in the end, all three Strings are added to the list. The `insert` function returns a `ListInterface` simply to allow this shorter syntax.

You want all these methods to insert elements to `list`, so you should make sure that your method returns itself:

```
public ListInterface insert(E d) {
    Node c = new Node(d, null, current);
    current.prior = c;

    return this;
}
```